# Service starts when called, but not on startup

Tags: upstart

I wrote a simple upstart script that kicks off a python program, I have it saved as `vgpusher.conf`.

It doesn't start automatically, but if I run `sudo start vgpusher` it starts and runs just fine.

The code is simple:

```
description "vgpush"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

script
    cd /home/computer/
    python pusher.py
end script
```

I placed the script in `/etc/init`. Other than that, I have done no configuration.

The machine is running Ubuntu 10.04 Server.

Do I need to take an extra step for the service to start on startup?

Comment: Please explain in more detail how you have configured your script as a service: where did you put vgpusher.conf, what is the contents of this file, where did you set the runlevel etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you don't need script:

```
description "vgpush"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

chdir /home/computer
exec python pusher.py
```

Second, it may help to log the output. If you upgrade to 12.04 (Highly recommended!) you will have a log in /var/log/upstart/$jobname.log. For 10.04, you have to do it manually:

```
description "vgpush"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

chdir /home/computer
exec python pusher.py 2>&1 >> /var/log/vgpush.log
```

That may give some clue. If I had to guess, it is because vgpush needs a network interface to be up that is not, and 10.04 starts runlevel 2 before all network interfaces are ready.

Answer (score 1):

When troubleshooting an upstart job, there are a few things to check.

1. Check the upstart job is correct. Yours looks pretty good, but I would suggest using the full path to the python executable ( /usr/bin/python ).
2. Check the upstart job log. there is a log file for each job at /var/log/upstart/.log It's possible that your job is starting and failing for some reason (maybe pusher.py needs the network to be up) and this log file will probably have information on that. At the least, it will at least show if the job is trying to start.

Comment: Using an explicit python path is not necessary. PATH will be set to the system default and the system python will always be in the default system path.